# WordPress database connection not working after port change

Tags: iis, database, port, wordpress, database-connection

I've recently changed a WordPress site that is hosted on a local server from port `80` to port `8080`. I did this initially just by editing the binding in IIS.

The site kept redirecting itself back to port `80`. After some Googling, I found the following line in the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mydomain.com');
```

I changed this to:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mydomain.com:8080');
```

With this, it no longer redirected to port `80`, but I got the error:

> Error establishing a database connection

Looking further into the `wp-config.php` file, I tried changing

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

to

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8080');
```

but still get the same database connection error.

I've tried

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8080');
define('DB_HOST', '192.10.115.552:8080'); // Take this as the servers static ip address
define('DB_HOST', 'www.mydomain.com:8080');
```

All of these give the same error message. I also found a setting for debugging which I turned to `true` With that, I get the following messages:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1529
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=7700 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1529
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1529

Comment: The is no need to change the DB port when you change the HTTP port. The MySQL Port stays the same.

Comment: Change you `DB_HOST` setting back to `localhost` without any ports and look at your error logs.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Where do I find the error logs? If I simply attempt to access wp-admin I get the error message `Could not find site www.mydomain.co.za:8080. Searched for table rs_blogs in database marc. Is that right?`

Comment: You have to change "site-url" in the tables wp_options if you decide to do this that way. Otherwhise you should not have to make that change in wordpress at all. The initial problem you had with the browser was just the browsers cache.

Comment: WordPress has [detailed instructions for moving a site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) (yes, changing the port is "moving").